# What is the difference between using '&&' and '||' over a ternary operator ('?' and ':')?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

In JavaScript, what is the difference between using

```
true ? 'Hello' : 'Goodbye' //Evaluates to "Hello"

false ? 'Hello' : 'Goodbye' //Evaluates to "Goodbye"
```

and

```
true && 'Hello' || 'Goodbye' //Evaluates to "Hello"

false && 'Hello' || 'Goodbye' //Evaluates to "Goodbye"
```

Comment: The latter is dependent on the value at `"Hello"` being truthy. Consider `true && false || true` vs `true ? false : true`

Comment: The first is much more readable IMO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are two different concepts that happen to give you the same answer.

---

The first example uses the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and **its result depends *only* on the first operand** (in your example `true`/`false`):

```
true ? 'Hello' : 'Goodbye' //Evaluates to "Hello"
false ? 'Hello' : 'Goodbye' //Evaluates to "Goodbye"
```

It is a shorthand form of an `if`/`else`. If the first operand is truthy, return the second operand (`Hello`). If the first operand is falsy, return the third operand (`Goodbye`).

The first expression of your first example can be rewritten as:

```
if (true)
    return 'Hello';
else
    return 'Goodbye';
```

---

The second example makes use of [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and **its result depends on *both* the first and the second operand**.

```
true && 'Hello' || 'Goodbye' //Evaluates to "Hello"
false && 'Hello' || 'Goodbye' //Evaluates to "Goodbye"
```

If `firstOperand && secondOperand` evaluates to a truthy value, return `secondOperand`. If they evaluate to something falsy, return `thirdOperand` (`Goodbye`).

In your examples, since a non-empty string is truthy, `true && 'Hello'` evaluates to `Hello`, and `false && 'Hello'` evaluates to `false`.

So your second example turns into:

```
'Hello' || 'Goodbye'
false || 'Goodbye'
```

Because of how [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) works, that happens to output what your first example outputs, but they're different concepts.

Notice how in the first example, we know what to return after evaluating the first operand. In the second example, we have to evaluate the first *two* operands before we know what to return.

Comment: `P && A || B` will not behave like a ternary when A is falsy.  The example might be clearer with Numeric arguments.  Eg `true && 0 || 7` will  result in 7.  Compare to `true ? 0 : 7` which results in zero.  Similar with empty string, null, anything falsy.

Answer (score 5):

## Ternary operator

This is a short hand of `if else`.

```
true ? 'Hello' : 'Goodbye'
```

is equivalent to

```
if (true) {
    'Hello'
} else {
    'Goodbye'
}
```

## Logical predicates

whereas `true && 'Hello' || 'Goodbye'` is not an `if else` condition

```
true && 'Hello' || 'Goodbye'
```

is equivalent to

```
(true && 'Hello') || 'Goodbye'
```

This results in `Hello` but it's based on precedence. Consider the case of

```
'Goodbye' || (true && 'Hello')
```

This will result in `Goodbye`. Changing the order changes the output but that doesn't happen with a ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there is no difference in outcome. BUT i had a guess on how they get processed. `()?:` is actually a tiny bit faster than `&&||` (See demonstration below).

`(A)B?C:` basically is a IF-Shorthand, so the `(A)` part gets evaluated and either the `B then` or `C else` stack is picked.

`(A)&&B||C` <strike>gets evaluated entirely</strike>. First the `(A)` gets evaluated. After that some [implicit conversion(Boolean conversion)](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839) happens - which takes a bit of time

> false - thx to "Gust van de Wal"
>
> Still a difference: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztnkrp9s)

```js
var max = 1e7;

var start1 = (new Date()).getTime();
for( var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  let a = (i%2) ? max-i : max+1;
  let b = (i%3) ? max-i : max+i;
}
var stop1 = (new Date()).getTime();

var start2 = (new Date()).getTime();
for( var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  let a = (i%2) && max-i || max+i;
  let b = (i%3) && max-i || max+i;
}
var stop2 = (new Date()).getTime();

console.log( (new Date()).getTime() );

console.log( stop1 -start1 );
console.log( stop2 -start2 );
```

Comment: [Short-circuiting logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#Short-circuit_evaluation) are definitely a thing, though

Comment: There is actually another difference. It is useful for branchless-code. Which prevents branch-prediction fails.

Comment: My point is that you've got a mistake in your answer. "(A)&&B||C gets evaluated entirely" is untrue when A and B are both truthy

Comment: Aye, you are right! Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztnkrp9s/). There still is a difference in exactly one case.

Comment: There "still" is? The short-circuiting explains the behaviour, so I don't really understand what you're getting at here

Answer (score 1):

Your first case is an example of inline if statements, while your second is an example of logical predicates.